# Requesting URL with UTF-8 characters from VBA code

Tags: html, vba, ms-access, utf-8

I am requesting results from this API:
http://mlrs.research.um.edu.mt/resources/gabra-api/

Everything works fine except when I introduce Maltese characters (which are UTF-8).

If I manually request the data using the following URLs, the return is correct.
[http://mlrs.research.um.edu.mt/resources/gabra-api/lexemes/search?s=għar](http://mlrs.research.um.edu.mt/resources/gabra-api/lexemes/search?s=g%C4%A7ar)

...search?s=ċar (can't post more than two links yet.)

When using the following code, the return is blank.

```
{"results":[],"query":{"page":1,"page_size":20,"result_count":0,"term":"g?ar","search_lemma":true,"search_wordforms":true,"search_gloss":true,"pending":false,"pos":null,"source":null}}

{"results":[],"query":{"page":1,"page_size":20,"result_count":0,"term":"?ar","search_lemma":true,"search_wordforms":true,"search_gloss":true,"pending":false,"pos":null,"source":null}}
```

Note ? replacing ħ and ċ characters - that's only because I copied these from the immediate window.

This is the code I am using to make the requests:

```
Public Function GetWebSource(ByRef Url As String) As String
  Dim xml As IXMLHTTPRequest
  On Error Resume Next
  Set xml = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
  With xml
    .Open "GET", Url, False
    .send
    GetWebSource = .responseText
  End With
  Set xml = Nothing
End Function
```

Because VBA IDE does not support these characters, tests will need to be done from a form field.

Any help, much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL contains some non ASCII characters, so you'll have to encode them beforehand:

```
Set xhr = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
xhr.Open "GET", "http://mlrs.research.um.edu.mt/resources/gabra-api/lexemes/search?s=g%C4%A7ar", False
xhr.Send
```